# Diciness with extracting things from a Hold'd expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have a list of param->value rules where the params are symbols that might have values assigned to them. For example:

```
{a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};
x = Hold[{a->1, b->2, c->3}];
```

I need the list wrapped in Hold otherwise it would evaluate to {1->1, 2->2, 3->3}.  (I'm open to any alternatives to Hold there if it makes the rest of this easier.)

Now suppose I want to convert x into this:

```
{"a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3}
```

The following function will do that:

```
f[h_] := Block[{a,b,c}, ToString[#[[1]]]->#[[2]]& /@ ReleaseHold@h]
```

My question: Can you write a version of f where the list of symbols {a,b,c} doesn't have to be provided explicitly?

Comment: Something like this seems like it almost works: `Block[Names["Global`*"], ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way using [Unevaluated](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
In[1]:= {a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};

In[2]:= x = Hold[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}];

In[3]:= ReleaseHold[
 x /. (symb_ -> e_) :> ToString[Unevaluated[symb]] -> e]

Out[3]= {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}
```

Comment: Using SymbolName instead of ToString also works. Curious if there's much reason to prefer one or the other.

Comment: @dreeves That is interesting.  According to the Help, 'SymbolName always gives the short name without any context.  ToString takes the settings of $Context and $ContextPath into account'.

Answer (score 1):

```
{a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};
x = Hold[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}];
f[x_] := Cases[x, HoldPattern[z_ -> y_] :> 
                  StringTake[ToString[(Hold@z)], {6, -2}] -> y, 2];
f[x] // InputForm
```

Out:

```
{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}
```

Perhaps not very elegant, but seems to work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm worried about that `StringTake[..., {6,-2}]`.  How robust is that to long variable names and arbitrary stuff on right-hand side of the rules?  Oh, is it just to extract whatever's inside that Hold[...]? Maybe that's safe enough.

Comment: @dreeves SymbolName[] returns a string, so I think any symbol can be safely treated as a string ... And yes, it's just for getting out the Hold[] argument.

Comment: @dreeves The rhs of the rule remains untouched. The lhs is a Hold[SymbolName] thing, so I guess it's safe

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an old question, but I think there's an answer that combines the virtues of both [Andrew Moylan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746899/diciness-with-extracting-things-from-a-holdd-expression/4747952#4747952) and [belisarius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746899/diciness-with-extracting-things-from-a-holdd-expression/4747284#4747284). You really want to have lists of rules with `HoldPattern` on the left-hand side, instead of lists of rules that have `Hold` wrapped around the whole thing, so that you can actually use the rules without having to go through any sort of `ReleaseHold` process.

```
In[1]:= {a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};
```

`Unevaluated` can also be helpful in constructing the sort of list you want:

```
In[2]:= x = Thread[HoldPattern /@ Unevaluated[{a, b, c}] -> Range[3]]
Out[2]= {HoldPattern[a] -> 1, HoldPattern[b] -> 2, HoldPattern[c] -> 3}
```

Now you can do what you want with rule replacement. It's a bit involved, but it's something I find myself doing over and over and over again. You may notice that this list of rules has almost exactly the form of a list of `OwnValues` or `DownValues`, so being able to manipulate it is very helpful. The trick is using `HoldPattern` and [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VerbatimPatterns.html) in concert:

```
In[3]:= f[rules_] :=
         Replace[rules,
          HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][s_Symbol] -> rhs_] :>
           With[{string = ToString[Unevaluated[s]]},
            string -> rhs], {1}]
```

The level spec on `Replace` is just there to make sure nothing unexpected happens if `rhs` is itself a rule or list of rules.

```
In[4]:= f[x] // InputForm
Out[4]= {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}
```